# I get POST 500 Internal Server Error on hosting while it works fine on localhost

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The error is "POST mywebsite.com/login.php 500 (Internal Server Error)"
Here is my header file which I doubt it may cause the problem but I dont know how to solve and why:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ajanda Uygulaması</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--BOOTSTRAP CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--BOOTSTRAP JAVASCRIPT-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--W3 CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<!--CUSTOM CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
    <!--JQUERY UI-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery-ui/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!--FONTAWESOME ICONS-->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e3f3a6e99c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

When the user click on login, the below script is executed:

```
$(".choice").click(function(){

    var choosen_id=$(this).attr("id");
    $(".choice").removeClass("choosen");
    $("#" + choosen_id).addClass("choosen");

    $("form").hide().promise().then(function() {
        $("#" + choosen_id + "-form").show();
    });

});

$(".login-button").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var loginType = $(this).attr("id");
    if(loginType=="manager_login"){

        if($("#manager_password").val()){
            
            var password = $("#manager_password").val();
            $.ajax({  
                type: 'POST',  
                url: 'login.php', 
                data: { manager_password: password },
                success: function(response) { 
                    if(response==1){
                        window.location.replace("manager.php");
                    }else{
                        $("#error").text(response); 
                    }
                    
                }
            });
        }else{
    
            $("#manager_password").css("outline", "2px solid #1f1a87");
        }


    }else if(loginType="inst_login"){
        if($("#inst_password").val()){
            var password = $("#inst_password").val();
            $.ajax({  
                type: 'POST',  
                url: 'login.php', 
                data: { inst_password: password },
                success: function(response) { 
                    if(response==1){
                        window.location.replace("instructor.php");
                    }else{
                        $("#error").text(response); 
                    }
                    
                }
            });
        }else{
            $("#inst_password").css("outline", "2px solid #1f1a87");
        }
    }

});
```

And that script posts data to below script.At this point, I get 500 internal server error :

```
 <?php

include 'includes/class-autoload.inc.php';
if(isset($_POST["manager_password"])){
    $managersObj = new ManagersContr();
    $managersObj->checkManager($_POST["manager_password"]);
}
else if(isset($_POST["inst_password"])){
    $instObj = new InstsContr();
    $instObj->checkInst($_POST["inst_password"]);
}
```

Also here is the ManagersContr class codes :

```
    <?php

class ManagersContr extends Managers{

    public function checkManager($password){

        $results = $this->getManager($password);

        if($results){

            foreach ($results as $result) {

                if($results){
                    if(isset($_SESSION)){
                        session_unset();
                    }
                    $_SESSION["manager_full_name"]=$result["manager_full_name"];

                    $_SESSION["manager_id"]=$result["manager_id"];

                    $_SESSION["permission_level"]=$result["permission_level"];
                    echo 1;
                    
                    /*

                    $_SESSION["full_name"]=$result["full_name"];

                    $_SESSION["permission_level"]=$result["permission_level"];

                    $_SESSION["id"]=$result["password"];

                    //Eğitmen sayfasına yönlendir
                    if($_SESSION["permission_level"]==3){
                        header("Location: instructor.php");
                    }

                    //2.Seviye yönetici sayfasına yönlendir
                    else if($_SESSION["permission_level"]==2){
                        header("Location: moderator.php");
                    }

                    //1.Seviye yönetici sayfasına
                    else if($_SESSION["permission_level"]==1){
                        header("Location: admin.php");
                    }

                    else{
                        echo "Bir hata oluştu";
                    }
                    */

                }

            }

        }else{
            echo "Böyle bir yönetici parolası yok";}        

        }   

    }
```

Comment: `;}` ?? Is that supposed to be a smilly

Comment: @RiggsFolly That looks like a typo, but extra `;`s shouldn't really cause any issues by themselves.

Comment: First check that `includes/class-autoload.inc.php` exists and the class definition for  `ManagersContr` as there is not much else to go wrong in that PHP script

Comment: I fixed the extra ; and I am still having the issue. You can see here live : http://alfawebtasarim.com/ajn2/    just type something and console will throw internal server error

Comment: _Small Point, but note the main issue_ Your javascript expects a returned value (1) and your PHP makes no attempt to pass back anything !! Is this the COMPLETE script??

Comment: @RiggsFolly They are fine I think.Because they are the exact same folder I runned on localhost and worked fine

Comment: But if they didnt get copied up to the live server, or one did and the other didnt etc etc etc

Comment: If you mean isset(manager_script) and isset(insts_script) , then yes,its not the full script.But I am not sure I understood what you are pointing at

Comment: Well ERROR 500 comes from a PHP script running on the server. So may I suggest it is going to be difficult for US to spot an error in YOUR code when you do not show us all of it, we are not clairvoyant

Comment: In fact it could be quite possible that the error is in the `ManagerContr` class or the method you are calling so it would be useful to see that also

Comment: @dudi I suggest to go to your web server error_log, and check what happen in there. From there you can work on that actually. Thanks

Comment: @RiggsFolly okay sir I editted and added the full code with managerscontr class codes

Comment: @BilhasryRamadhony I accidentaly deleted the files inside folder "log".I tought it automatically creates files but nothing happens and folder "logs" is just an empty folder now.Can you help me what can I do ?

Comment: Youare using SESSION but I dont see a `session_start()` anywhere

Comment: @RiggsFolly session_start() is at includes/class-autoload.inc.php

Comment: @RiggsFolly I would like to send you the whole project folders from a contact you may give me if you would help.And if you help, it will be priceless for me

Comment: @dudi try to put this in your login.php, error_reporting(E_ALL); So it would be like this

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// your code start here
.
.

Comment: @bilhasry Ramadhony I have put it on includes/class-autoload.inc.php which is included by every page.I am afraid its a javascript error :/

Comment: @dudi can u do var_dump($results) after this line $results = $this->getManager($password); , will it show associative array or stdClass object. Thanks

Comment: Like I said before, Error 500 is an PHP Error

Comment: Not sure what you are hosting with but if you use IIS, you have to turn error displaying for localhosts in IIS config.

Comment: I just tried http://alfawebtasarim.com/ajn2/ and when I submit nothing happens except the normal page reloading. Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: @kmoser this is the problem and I couldnt fix it.It works on localhost but on the live host,it gives internal server error when you click the button

Comment: @dudi The live host I tested didn't give an error.

Comment: @kmoser it does.you can see when you check the console